# How to make schema and apply populate query in mongodb node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have 2 documents

products :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5981c1557e713838bb24d350"),
    "Status" : "Enable",
    "Product_length" : 10.0,
    "Product_Name" : "LG 24LF452A 60 cm (24') LED TV HD Ready",
    "Product_height" : 5.0,
    "User_Object_ID" : "594b57c97ac6860cfe96c95a",
    "Type" : "Product",
    "Product_Status" : "Approved"
}
```

product_price

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5981c1557e713838bb24d352"),
    "Product_id" : "5981c1557e713838bb24d350",
    "Price" : 14495.0,
    "SKU" : "compart000077",
}
```

schemas

```
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    Product_Name                    :{type: String},
    Status                          :{type: String},
    Product_length                  :{type: String},
    Product_height                  :{type: String},
    User_Object_ID                  :{type: String},
    Type                            : {type:String},
    Product_Status                  : {type: String}

});

const product_priceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    SKU                      : {type : String},
    Product_id               : {type : String},
  Price                    : {type : Number}

});
```

I want to apply a populate query on it by which I can find price of a product with its product_id.I don't know how to make schema for this and apply populate query on it.
Please help

Comment: add your product schema and product_price schema in question.

Comment: combine both documents into one (i.e add price details in product details) and query like db.products.find({_id : "id of product"})

Comment: I dont know how to make schema for this which is actually my question

Comment: I had updated my schemas above. And my question is different in such a way that the answer provided above How do I query referenced objects in MongoDB? has query about aggregation and here I am asking about populate and the schema I made is proper or not I dont know